# Parcelize complains "Parcelable should be a class" on objects and enums

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, kotlin-android-extensions

When I try to annotate an `enum class` or `object` with `@Parcelize`, it results in the error `'Parcelable' should be a class`, both as an editor hint and as a compile failure. I can `@Parcelize` classes just fine, but I can't do things like

```
@Parcelize object MySingletion : Parcelable
@Parcelize enum class Direction : Parcelable { N, E, W, S }
```

This happens even though the Kotlin website [explicitly states](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#supported-types) that objects and enums are supported. Is there a way to fix this so that I can `@Parcelize` these types of classes? And ideally, is there a solution that doesn't involve manually coding the parceler logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documented support means, that *objects and enums* are properly handled when used as properties on the *class* being *parcelized*. More importantly both types are implicitly excluded from the usage, as the fields have to be properties defined within the primary constructor:

> `@Parcelize` requires all serialized properties to be declared in the primary constructor. Android Extensions will issue a warning on each property with a backing field declared in the class body. Also, `@Parcelize` can't be applied if some of the primary constructor parameters are not properties.

If you need to use your *objects or enums* as a property only, there's no issue with it. If you want to use it as a `Parcelable`, you can't get around implementing the interface by yourself, since both types are a kind of a singleton implementation and `@Parcelize` only supports types with accessible constructors with properties.

Answer (score 8):

Since Kotlin 1.2.60, the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/ChangeLog.md#tools-android-extensions) states that Parcelize works with object and enum types.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that this works: @Parcelize enum class MyEnum : Parcelable {A,B}